# How do I fix this for loop problem in C++?

Tags: c++

I have this for loop problem in my c++ program. When i try to run it it's all working fine but there is a small problem in the "Enter name:" loop. The "Enter name:" outputs 5 times but the first "Enter name:" is not recognized as part of the loop but instead the 6th empty line before the last "Enter name:" loop is recognized as one but it does not have a "Enter name:" in it, it is just an empty line with no words but the program recognized it as part of the loop not the one in the very first line with the "Enter name:". Can someone help me to fix and recognize the first line with the "Enter name:" as part of the loop and not recognize the 6th line of the program as part of the loop.

[image: This is the program output]

This is my code for my c++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char names[5][20],t[20];
    int i,j;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Enter name: ";
        cin.getline( names[i], 20 );
    }
        {
                cout<<" ";
                cin>>names[i];
        }
        for(i=1; i<5; i++)
        {
                for(j=1; j<5; j++)
                {
                        if(strcmp(names[j-1], names[j])>0)
                        {
                                strcpy(t, names[j-1]);
                                strcpy(names[j-1], names[j]);
                                strcpy(names[j], t);
                        }
                }
        }
        cout<<"\n Names Sorted in Alphabetical Order : \n\n";
        for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
                cout<<" ";
                cout<<names[i]<<"\n";
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program has **undefined behavior** because `i` is not initialized and you're using that uninitialized `i` in `cin >>names[i];`

Comment: Also, you need to **remove** the `{cout<<" ";cin>>names[i];}` block as it is not part of any `for` loop.

Comment: @AnoopRana `i` is initialized, its value is 5 (initialized at 0 in the previous loop and exited at 5). The undefined behaviour is the illegal access to `names[i]` (6th element to an array of 5...)

Comment: The `{ cout << " "; cin >> names[i]; }` block seems entirely spurious and unnecessary (as well as causing UB, as mentioned above). Remove that block then just change the `i = 1` to `i = 0` in the following `for` loop.

Comment: You have two different `i` variables. The one defined in your first `for` loop "shadows" that defined in the `main` function.

Comment: @Fareanor `i` is uninitialized and it does not have value `5`. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/bO4W7Auo6). When you run the above linked demo, you will find that i have added a `cout` for `i` which prints garbage value and not `5`.

Comment: @AnoopRana Oh my bad, i didn't see `i` was redeclared in the for loop (instead of using the already defined one)

Comment: Even removing the second `i`, attempting to access `names[5]` is undefined behaviour - the last element is `names[4]`.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes it's the issue I pointed out in my first comment ^^

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code:

##### Mistake 1

The variable `i` is **uninitialized** and you're using that uninitialized variable when you wrote:

```
cin>>names[i]; //this is undefined behavior since `i` is uninitialized
```

which leads to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

##### Mistake 2

You have an unnecessary block(given below) in your code:

```
{
    cout<<" ";
    cin>>names[i];
}
```

The above block does not belong to any `for` loops and is completely unnecessary. You should remove the above shown block.

Additionally, you need to take care of the fact that you must not go **out of bounds** of any of the array in your program. For example, say if you have an array named `arr` of length `5` then you can safely access elements: `arr[0]`,`arr[1]`,`arr[2]`,`arr[3]` and `arr[4]`. But if we try to access `arr[5]` then it will lead to undefined behavior.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: `>` is formatting for quotes. When it is a quote include a reference to the source, when it isnt one, better don't use quote formatting

Comment: Who said i can't quote myself? See my profile(about) for some of my selected quotes :)

Comment: a quote should come with a reference to the source.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't agree. Well i usually write my name under any quote i write but here i don't think it is needed because my name is already there at the bottom right of the answer. Btw, are you suggesting that i should add a cpp official link to the quote or something else(like the person who wrote the quote)?

Comment: I am just saying that `>` is for formatting quotes. Using it to format something that is not quoting from somewhere is confusing.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I got your point. Thanks for the suggestion. Its just that i see no problem with the way i use `>` in this context since i am quoting myself.

Comment: quoting from where? Its not from your profile

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Who said you can't(use) quote(s) in answers on SO?

Comment: Nobody. I think I did explain my comment already. We can leave it at that. I was just curious but if you don't want to tell me where the quote is from its ok

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes lets leave it at that. My point is that by reading a lot  of books and writing/reading c++ code, i can say something about a given topic(in my own words). Those sentences are just that: my own understanding of the topic. One of the reason that i used `<` is that i wanted those statements to stand out from the rest of the answer.